# React-Native run-android command issue

Tags: android, react-native

When starting android project with React-Native it is giving this error:

> React-Native Command run-android unrecognized.Did you mean to run this inside a react-native project?

Comment: Did u initialize a project in that directory using react-native init ?

Comment: If you follow the Getting Started Doc on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content you shouldn´t get this issue. Just look if you installed the requirements and than follow the Quick Start Guide everything should be fine...Where did you run the command?

Comment: @Andrea yes i followed this but the issue was within HAXM now its working
Thanks,

Comment: This to me was happening for an old version of node

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try to do `npm install` before `react-native run-android`

Comment: i installed npm using npm install but still its saying  Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

Comment: @sud007 What is the issue you are facing? Please post the error and steps you are following

Comment: I had to delete the node_modules folder first and then run npm install again to get mine to run react-native run-android again.

Answer (score 8):

First we have to install react-native then upgrade packages if you need and run android.

```
npm install --save react-native@latest

react-native upgrade

react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 6):

A lot of developers fail to mention the crucial point,that certain commands require you to be a particular directory. In this case, to "react-native run-android", you have to be in your project directory!

Answer (score 3):

Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

I faced this issue, the problem is we need to navigate to or project folder.

example: I created the project in "MyApps" with app name "DemoApp" in D drive

the command line root should be like this:
D:\MyApps\DemoApp>react-native run-android

now it will  run with out any issue.

The problem is your android related info is presents inside the app not t=in the main directory.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and the above solutions did not work. Try using:

```
yarn add react-native-cli
```

Comment: Also this not work for ma it's says "'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: you need too install yarn first

Comment: and How to do that ?

Comment: @VISH you should use npm i -g react-native-cli

Answer (score 1):

First of all please see if devices/emulator is attached and working by following command

```
adb devices
```

there should be some devices showing connected
it is better to restart/reconnect you emulator/device and then try to run application again
if not working you can also try

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you are inside the project like cd AwesomeProject and do npm i and after that execute npx react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I was in the **android folder** of my project due to this command **`cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`**.So the solution was to **`cd ../`** and come to root of project and then running this command

`react-native run-android --variant=release`

ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was I was not inside the project directory AwesomeProject( Project that I created using this command :

```
react-native init AwesomeProject )
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed after adding Android sdk-tools to PATH, and restarting VSCode/Terminal.

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools
```

Earlier my path set to

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk
```

Answer (score -2):

1.make sure java jdk installed
2.make sure npm installed in your project root folder
3.this works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).